# How to populate selected value inside a input-field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bootstrap drop-down with input field,my drop-down is consist of checkbox to select multiple values

What i am trying to do is when user checks any drop-down it should get populated inside the input field with a comma separator,so that  user can select multiple users

**and the tricky part i am trying to do is**

-in my drop-down currently i have 3 drop-downs which have different values and text

- These are text:`dheeraj` value:`draj.121@gmail.com` and so on for all
- so indrop-down i am displaying text as `dheeraj` but when user clicks on user i want to populateinput field with `draj.121@gmail.com` which is value of that drop-down

```js
$(".checkbox-menu").on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
  $(this).closest("li").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
});

$(document).on('click', '.allow-focus', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <label for="subCategoryCode">TO :</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="To" id="To">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu checkbox-menu allow-focus" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="draj.121@gmail.com"> Dheeraj
     </label></li>

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="raju.45@gmail.com"> Raju
     </label></li>

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="ravi456@gmail.com"> Ravi
     </label></li>


      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and also when user deselect the check-box i want to remove that value from input field

please anyone give me some ideas to do this, thankyou

Comment: what will be te result if he select multiple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the check box and append the value to a variable and assign to text field like this

```
$(".checkbox-menu").on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
 $(this).closest("li").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
 var sList = "";
 $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        sList += $(this).val() + ","
    }
});

 $("#To").val(sList.slice(0,-1));
});

$(document).on('click', '.allow-focus', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6h1074bL/

Comment: hey i have a small doubt?

Comment: What is the problem

Comment: sir i have a json string `[
  {
    "value": "draj.121@gmail.com",
    "name": "dheeraj"
  },
  {
    "value": "raju",
    "name": "raju45@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "value": "ravi",
    "name": "ravi456@gmail.com"
  }
]`  how can i dynamically create that dropdown with chgeckbox

Comment: Check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/nq4yvfh3/ this is not the part of your question